# What is the single line of code required to change a preference in 2.8?

Tags: scripting

I am trying to use one line of code in the console to toggle...

Preferences>Navigation>Orbit Around Selection

```
bpy.context.user_preferences.view.use_rotate_around_active = True
```

This line works fine in 2.79 and updates the user preference window.

```
bpy.types.PreferencesInput.use_rotate_around_active = True
```

This is my best shot at the equivalent code in 2.8rc. Nothing happens and yet there is no error message either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself via "Blender 2.80: Preferences API" although it should have been easier to track down.

```
bpy.context.preferences.inputs.use_rotate_around_active=True
```